# wget command is not working on one particular internal web-site

Tags: 18.04, wget

I'm working on a server with Ubuntu 18.04 OS.

I've double checked every network configuration.

The "wget" works fine with practically every website I'm trying to download from. Although there's one internal web-site that I'm trying to download from it a certain app and it's no working. I have the same server with the same configuration of network as well as hardware but it runs on Ubuntu 16.04 and there it works fine also on the internal web-site.

[Messages I'm getting(a lot of the info on the pic is restricted)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTEqI.jpg)

Please advice on how to continue from this point. I'm pretty lost here.

Comment: With that much information redacted, the best help you can get is probably that you should check your routing tables, and verify that you have a valid route, and that the remote machine is in fact answering.

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: @vidarlo thank you for the reply. I've double checked the routing and I do have connection with the machine.
For example, if I'm trying to download driver from official nvidia website with "wget" I can download. 
Though from a specific internal website I can't download ONLY on ubuntu 18.04.